# Not able to display data when component loads using Angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to make a table using [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). The problem that I face is that in the starting the table does not show any data. But pagination has updated number of data size.  Not able to understand how to make data available as soon as the component loads.

As you can see on the right it shows 52 total records present.
[image]

And as soon as I click on some table header to sort or if I click next of pagination the rows are populated with data.

Would really appreciate suggestions to rectify this.

Thanks

Html file

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.snipsOutput.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="input">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header>User Query</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.snipsOutput.input}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Hotword Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="hotword">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header>Hotword</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.snipsOutput.hotword}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
    [length]="dataSource.data.length"
    [pageIndex]="0"
    [pageSize]="10"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

NluDataTableComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { NluDataTableDataSource } from './nlu-data-table-datasource';
import { PfivaDataService } from '../services/pfiva-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nlu-data-table',
  templateUrl: './nlu-data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nlu-data-table.component.css']
})
export class NluDataTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: NluDataTableDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'input', 'hotword', 'intent', 'timestamp', 'feedbackQuery', 'feedbackUserResponse', 'feedbackTimestamp'];

  constructor(private pfivaDataService: PfivaDataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new NluDataTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, this.pfivaDataService);
  }
}
```

NluDataTableDataSource.ts

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { NLUData } from '../data-model/NLUData';
import { PfivaDataService } from '../services/pfiva-data.service';

/**
 * Data source for the NluDataTable view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed data
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class NluDataTableDataSource extends DataSource<NLUData> {
  //data: NluDataTableItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;
  data: NLUData[] = [];

  constructor(private paginator: MatPaginator, 
    private sort: MatSort, private pfivaDataService: PfivaDataService) {
      super();
      this.fetchNLUData();
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<NLUData[]> {
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
    // stream for the data-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    // Set the paginators length
    this.paginator.length = this.data.length;

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the table is being destroyed. Use this function, to clean up
   * any open connections or free any held resources that were set up during connect.
   */
  disconnect() {}

  private fetchNLUData() {
    this.pfivaDataService.getNLUData()
    .subscribe(
      (nluData: NLUData[]) => this.data = nluData,
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  /**
   * Paginate the data (client-side). If you're using server-side pagination,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getPagedData(data: NLUData[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  /**
   * Sort the data (client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: NLUData[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'id': return compare(+a.snipsOutput.id, +b.snipsOutput.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

/** Simple sort comparator for example ID/Name columns (for client-side sorting). */
function compare(a, b, isAsc) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Comment: try this ngOnInit() {
    setTimeOut(()=>this.dataSource = new NluDataTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, this.pfivaDataService),1000)
  }

Answer (score 1):

You are not emitting anything to the table when the data is loaded.

The problem is here.

```
observableOf(this.data)
```

That data is loaded later here.

```
this.pfivaDataService.getNLUData()
.subscribe(
  (nluData: NLUData[]) => this.data = nluData,
  (error) => console.log(error)
);
```

The `connect(): Observable<NLUData[]>` function needs to emit data when the data changes. Since you using pagination and sorting the data first, then it needs to also emit when those values change.

I would use a `combineLatest()` instead of `merge` because it will emit when any of the input observables emit a value.

```
return combineLatest(
     this.pfivaDataService.getNLUData(),
     this.paginator.page,
     this.sort.sortChange
).pipe(map(latest) => {
        // latest is an array of 3 in the order above

        // do data processing here
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but i don't understand this line //latest is an array of 3 in the order above and what kind of data processing is to be done

Comment: @RahulLao it will emit an array of 3 items in the order the arguments were past to `combineLatest`.